# do numbers in random.randrange have to be both integers?

Tags: python, random

I want to generate a random number between two numbers, but sometimes one of them or both will not be an integer (it will be a float). I understand that there can be so many possible numbers if one of them is a float and one of them is an integer, so I assigned a step as well (which is 1). This should produce a random number for me, but it gives me a value error that says

ValueError: non-integer arg 1 for randrange()

So I want to know if there is another random method that I can use so that it works with float values and integer values without giving me a value error.

Comment: Just cast your float to an int explicitly according to your desired logic (rounding up, down or truncating)…?!

Comment: Use [`random.uniform()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html?highlight=random#random.uniform).

Comment: @deceze but I want it to be a float number so I can't round it to an integer

Comment: Then you don’t want `randrange` at all, but `uniform`, as james says.